# Showing that $\frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{1+2^{\sqrt n}/x^n}$ is approximated by $2^{\sqrt n}\left(1- \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n} \right)$

Tags: calculus

Sorry for this inconvenient question but really I can't see how to show that $$\frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{1+ \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n}}\quad\text{is approximated by}\quad 2^{\sqrt n } \left(1- \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n} \right)$$

I know how to move from right to left but I can't achieve the inverse!

Comment: Also if you know how to go from 'right to left' you also know how to get from 'left to right'. Just calculate 'right to left' and then swap the direction. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to go from $\frac{a}{1+b}$ to $a(1-b)$, which is an approximation (but a good one) if $|b|\ll 1$. In this case $b=2^{\sqrt{n}}/x^n$, so the approximation works for large $n$ if $|x|>1$.

Comment: yes you are right, it is an approximation and I should modify the question. Is there a known name for this approximation?

Comment: $$\dfrac{a}{1+b} \cdot \dfrac{1-b}{1-b} = \dfrac{a(1-b)}{1-b^2}$$ and since $b^2 \to 0$ much faster than $b \to 0$, you have: $$\dfrac{a(1-b)}{1-b^2} \sim a(1-b)$$

Comment: @user008 I don't know a name for this explicitly, but it's obtained by linearizing a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of you for this help

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{x^n}}=\frac{x^n2^{\sqrt{n}}}{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}=2^{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{x^n}{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)=2^{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}-\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)=2^{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}}\right)$$
now you have to show that for your values of $x,n$:
$$x^n+2^{\sqrt{n}}\approx x^n$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{1+ \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n}}=2^{\sqrt n } \left(1- \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n} \right)\iff$

$2^{\sqrt n}= 2^{\sqrt n } (1- \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n})(1+ \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n})\iff$

$(1- \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n})(1+ \frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n})=1\iff$

$1- (\frac {2^{\sqrt n}}{x^n})^2 = 1\iff$

$\frac {4^{\sqrt n}}{x^{2n}} = 0$

Does $\frac {4^{\sqrt n}}{x^{2n}} \approx 0$?  Beat's me.  You seem to think so. If $|x|$ is large it does.  If $|x|>1$ and $n$ is large it does too.

But this actually depends on problem.